# How to avoid $watch service in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I just wanted to avoid the $watch service in my program. Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: Please post your code and state where you want what

Comment: could you provide an example of a watch your using? Then maybe we could help you

Comment: Why do you want to avoid $watch?

Comment: Sorry, you've been downvoted by people who don't know angularJS.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using watch with the following strategies:

1. $scope Communication
2. ngModel $parsers
3. ngModel $viewChangeListeners
4. setInterval
5. filters

Example using setInterval:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="myModel.myProp">
    <br>
    <input ng-model="myModel.myProp2">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  "use strict";
  angular.notifyMe = function(scope, expr, callbackFn) {
    var oldValue = scope.$eval(expr);
    setInterval(function() {
      var newValue = scope.$eval(expr);
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          callbackFn.call(null, newValue, oldValue);
          oldValue = newValue;
        },0);
      }
    }, 100);
  };
  angular.module("MyApp", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.myModel = {
      myProp: "Test Value",
      myProp2: "Test Value 2"
    };
    angular.notifyMe($scope, "myModel.myProp", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("int myProp value changed, new:" + newValue + ", old: " + oldValue);
    });
    angular.notifyMe($scope, "myModel.myProp2", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("int myProp2 value changed, new:" + newValue + ", old: " + oldValue);
    });
  });
</script>
```

More details [here](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/effective-strategies-avoiding-watches-angularjs/)

---

For angular2, you can use [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html):

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  prop: number;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

You can still use [OnChanges](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html#onchanges) on angular 1.5.

This hook allows us to react to changes of one-way bindings of a component. One-way bindings have also been introduced in Angular 1.5 and align a bit more with Angular 2’s uni-directional data flow. Let’s say we make the name property of our myCmp configurable from the outside world using a one-way binding:

```
mod.component('myCmp', {
  template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.name}}</h1>',
  bindings: {
    name: '<'
  },
  controller: MyCmpController
});
```

We can now bind an expression to the component’s name property like this:

```
<my-cmp name="someExpression"></my-cmp>
```

Let’s say we want to prepend the name with “Howdy” when the name is “Pascal” and otherwise simply greet with “Hello”. We can do that using the $onChanges() lifecycle hook. It gets called with an object that holds the changes of all one-way bindings with the currentValue and the previousValue.

```
function MyCmpController() {
  this.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    if (changesObj.name) {
      var prefix;
      (changesObj.name.currentValue === 'Pascal') ?
        prefix = 'Howdy ' : prefix = 'Hello ';
      this.name = prefix + this.name;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You could add components $onChanges()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy I have found for myself is to avoid `$scope` entirely. Bind the controller to the scope using `controller as`, and interact with the controller directly; then you can use simple Javascript mechanisms to detect changes. E.g., ES5 getters/setters:

```
class FooController {
    get bar() {
        return this._bar;
    }

    set bar(value) {
        this._bar = value;
        console.log(this._bar);
    }
}

angular.module('Baz', []).controller('FooController', FooController);
```

```
<div ng-controller="FooController as ctrl">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.bar">
    ...
```